# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start doesn't work in Default.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-c++

I have a project built with some parts in c++, some in asp.net/c#.

There is a `CHtmlView` built in c++ that call an aspx page (`Navigate2(..Default.aspx,NULL,NULL);`)

in `Default.aspx.cs` I call an external process e.g.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

In my PC with windows server 2003, it works fine. In an other PC, with windows 8 and IIS 8 nothing happens.

What is wrong? Do you have some suggestions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `Process.Start` in a page on your server, it will execute on the the server, not on the client. Since the IIS process isn't a User Interactive process, you won't see anything at all.

It will probably work on your development machine since IISExpress *is* a User Interactive process.

There is not much information to go with in your post what you want to achieve, but you might be looking for [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much, I replaced Process.Start with Response.Redirect and it works fine!