# Hide window task bar code not working on iis7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am working on hide task bar of window this code working fine on visual studo 2010 but not working  on IIS 7.5 and not give any error .Please tell me why this code not working on iis7.5 (window 7)

This is my code

```
public static class Taskbar
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count); 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int threadId, EnumThreadProc pfnEnum, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern System.IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string windowTitle);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHwnd, IntPtr childAfterHwnd, IntPtr className, string windowText);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

    private const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    private const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    private const string VistaStartMenuCaption = "Start";
    private static IntPtr vistaStartMenuWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    private delegate bool EnumThreadProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the taskbar.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Show()
    {
        SetVisibility(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hide the taskbar.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Hide()
    {
        SetVisibility(false);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the visibility of the taskbar.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool Visible
    {
        set { SetVisibility(value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hide or show the Windows taskbar and startmenu.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="show">true to show, false to hide</param>
    private static void SetVisibility(bool show)
    {
        // get taskbar window
        IntPtr taskBarWnd = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", null);

        // try it the WinXP way first...
        IntPtr startWnd = FindWindowEx(taskBarWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", "Start");

        if (startWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // try an alternate way, as mentioned on CodeProject by Earl Waylon Flinn
            startWnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)0xC017, "Start");
        }

        if (startWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            // ok, let's try the Vista easy way...
            startWnd = FindWindow("Button", null);

            if (startWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // no chance, we need to to it the hard way...
                startWnd = GetVistaStartMenuWnd(taskBarWnd);
            }
        }

        ShowWindow(taskBarWnd, show ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(startWnd, show ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the window handle of the Vista start menu orb.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="taskBarWnd">windo handle of taskbar</param>
    /// <returns>window handle of start menu</returns>
    private static IntPtr GetVistaStartMenuWnd(IntPtr taskBarWnd)
    {
        // get process that owns the taskbar window
        int procId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(taskBarWnd, out procId);

        Process p = Process.GetProcessById(procId);
        if (p != null)
        {
            // enumerate all threads of that process...
            foreach (ProcessThread t in p.Threads)
            {
                EnumThreadWindows(t.Id, MyEnumThreadWindowsProc, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }
        return vistaStartMenuWnd;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback method that is called from 'EnumThreadWindows' in 'GetVistaStartMenuWnd'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hWnd">window handle</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">parameter</param>
    /// <returns>true to continue enumeration, false to stop it</returns>
    private static bool MyEnumThreadWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(256);
        if (GetWindowText(hWnd, buffer, buffer.Capacity) > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(buffer);
            if (buffer.ToString() == VistaStartMenuCaption)
            {
                vistaStartMenuWnd = hWnd;
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to hide the taskbar on the web server?

Comment: You lack a basic understanding of how the web works.

Comment: Somewhat related question / answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840830/993547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because IIS runs as a Windows service and is therefore prohibited from interacting with the desktop.

Did you expect this to happen on the client? If your code did work, it would happen on the server, not the client. But it doesn't, so give up.